# How to copy files into a directory by AppleScript? Convert bash to AppleScript

Tags: finder, applescript, bash

How to copy files into a directory by AppleScript?  Convert bash to AppleScript.

Please convert the following bash commandline code into AppleScript.

```
cd /Volumes/B
cp f1.txt f2.txt drc
```

Similarly, convert the following bash commandline code into AppleScript.

```
cp /Volumes/B/f1.txt /Volumes/B/f2.txt /Volumes/B/drc
```

f1.txt and f2.txt are regular files.  drc is is a directory.  In the first code, the files and directory for cp are expressed as relative paths.  In the second code, they are absolute paths.  I am not sure whether AppleScript has the concepts of "current directory" and "relative path".

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the 2nd question, this should work

(detailing the step to make it clearer; you could make a loop)

```
tell application "Finder"
    set f1 to "B:f1.txt" as alias
    set f2 to "B:f2.txt" as alias
    set destpath to "B:drc:" as text

    duplicate f1 to folder (destpath)
    duplicate f2 to folder (destpath)
        
end tell
```